# get sql table data, save in array variable in one php file and display in another php file under a pre-created table

Tags: php, html, mysql

the question is a mouthful so I'll get straight into the explanation. I have two php files, index.php and server.php.

In index.php is a table I created. Currently I pull data from the database and display it in the table. Everything works fine. Code below:

Index.php:

```
<table class="w3-table-all w3-responsive w3-hoverable">
<tr class="w3-grey">
  <th><b>Project Name</b></th>
  <th><b>Project Number</b></th>
  <th><b>Description</b></th>
  <th><b>Area</b></th>
  <th><b>Project Leader Name</b></th>
  <th><b>Project Leader Email</b></th>
  <th><b>Project Leader Number</b></th>
  <th><b>Project Manager Name</b></th>
  <th><b>Project Manager Email</b></th>
  <th><b>Project Manager Number</b></th>
  <th><b></b>Project Team</th>
  <th><b></b>Project Status</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<?php
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "";
 $dbname = "db";

 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

 if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 } 

$sql = "SELECT pname, pnumber, description, area, plname, plemail, 
                plnumber, pmname, pmemail, pmnumber, pteam, status 
        FROM data 
        WHERE category='Radio'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<td>" . $row["pname"]. "</td><td>" . $row["pnumber"]. "</td><td>" . $row["description"] . "</td><td>" . $row["area"] . "</td><td>" . $row["plname"] . "</td><td>"
         . $row["plemail"] . "</td><td>" . $row["plnumber"] . "</td><td>" . $row["pmname"] . "</td><td>" . $row["pmemail"] . "</td><td>" . $row["pmnumber"] . "</td><td>"
         . $row["pteam"] . "</td><td>" . $row["status"] . "</td><td>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
</tr>
</table>
```

What I would like to have is the data being pulled from the database and the info saved in a variable in server.php, which I then can access again and display correctly under the table in index.php.

What I have tried so far in server.php is below:

server.php:

```
//Get variable from JS in index.php
if (isset($_POST['Category'])) {
    $gotcategory = $_POST['Category'];
    //$_SESSION['success'] = "Category has been set to $gotcategory"; //Debug 
    display for checking category variable

    // Select project information from database to display in table format
    $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'db');
    $sql = "SELECT pname, pnumber, description, area, plname, plemail, plnumber, pmname, pmemail, pmnumber, pteam, status FROM data WHERE category='$gotcategory'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $all_data = array();

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $toadd = "<td>" . $row["pname"]. "</td><td>" . $row["pnumber"]. "</td><td>" . $row["description"] . "</td><td>" . $row["area"] . "</td><td>" . $row["plname"] . "</td><td>"
             . $row["plemail"] . "</td><td>" . $row["plnumber"] . "</td><td>" . $row["pmname"] . "</td><td>" . $row["pmemail"] . "</td><td>" . $row["pmnumber"] . "</td><td>"
             . $row["pteam"] . "</td><td>" . $row["status"] . "</td><td>";
            $all_data[] = $toadd;
        }
        $_SESSION['Data'] = $alldata;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['Data'] = "No data";
    }
```

And back in the index.php:

```
<table class="w3-table-all w3-responsive w3-hoverable">
<tr class="w3-grey">
  <th><b>Project Name</b></th>
  <th><b>Project Number</b></th>
  <th><b>Description</b></th>
  <th><b>Area</b></th>
  <th><b>Project Leader Name</b></th>
  <th><b>Project Leader Email</b></th>
  <th><b>Project Leader Number</b></th>
  <th><b>Project Manager Name</b></th>
  <th><b>Project Manager Email</b></th>
  <th><b>Project Manager Number</b></th>
  <th><b></b>Project Team</th>
  <th><b></b>Project Status</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><?php echo ($_SESSION['Data'])?></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

For some reason this just doesn't seem to work. I get no output whatsoever, not even 'No data'.

I know it is a massive wall of text but any help with this will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Slalem

Comment: Why two separate files? Are they loaded by the browser at different times? If not, lookup ```include``` or ```require_once```. If they are displayed at different times, lookup ```$_SESSION```.

Comment: did you call `session_start()` in both files?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Index.php is them main file that is loaded by the browser, server.php is never really loaded but index.php and some other php files use some functions in server.php at different times. I don't want to repeat the same functions in each different php file that needs them, thus server.php.I have included server.php in index.php and session_start() is in server.php. If I add session_start() to index.php I get the error that the session has already been started.